# BLACS context value and multiple MPI communicators

Tags: c, mpi, intel-mkl, scalapack

I am trying to make some tests with BLACS/Scalapack (C interface, Intel MKL version) making use multiple MPI communicators: particularly, what I am trying to obtain is a set of BLACS contexts/grids corresponding (one-to-one) to a set of (disjoint) MPI communicators. While I have no problems in working with a single "global" communicator (`MPI_COMM_WORLD`) I have some difficulties with the multiple communicator case. I hope that you could give me some suggestions for the following problem.

I am a bit confused about the BLACS context variable value update after a call to `Cblacs_gridinit`: let's suppose to start with a "global" context corresponding to the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator. I can obtain the corresponding BLACS context with the call:

```
MPI_Comm globalCommunicator(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MKL_INT globalContext(Csys2blacs_handle(globalCommunicator));
```

and create a grid on it with

```
Cblacs_gridinit(&globalContext,
                &c_blacsGridOrdering,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskRow,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskCol);
```

with, for example, `char c_blacsGridOrdering('R')`.

The globalContext value in this case is 0.

At some point in my code, which is making use of 6 MPI tasks,
an MPI communicator (`localCommunicator`) corresponding to the group of 4 tasks with id `[0;3]` is being created: at this point I would like to create a new BLACS context (`localContext`) for this "local" communicator and a local grid on it. I can do that with the code

```
MKL_INT localContext(Csys2blacs_handle(localCommunicator));

Cblacs_gridinit(&localContext,
                &c_blacsGridOrdering,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskRowLocal,
                MKL_INT i_nTaskColLocal);
```

where the above function call sequence is performed only by the tasks included in the local communicator.

The `localContext` value, after the call to `Csys2blacs_handle`, is equal to 1 (for each task of the local communicator) but it is modified and set to 0 by the subsequent call to `Cblacs_gridinit`.

Obviously this causes some problems in the rest of my code since, for example, if I try to retrieve the MPI communicator corresponding to `localContext` with a call to `Cblacs2sys_handle` I get a six task communicator corresponding to the initial `globalCommunicator`.

Most likely I am making some very stupid error (missing call to some BLACS functions??) or it is not clear to me the interplay between multiple MPI communicators and BLACS context/grids but I can not find what is wrong with my code.

Do you have some suggestions concerning the above problem? Many thanks for your help!

### UPDATE 1

I have an update for my question which could be useful to find a solution or at least an explanation for the observed problem: the described problem is no more present if I initialize the first grid (the one making use of the global context) on a task grid whose size is such that all available MPI tasks are included, for example with `MKL_INT i_nTaskRow(1)` and `MKL_INT i_nTaskCol(MPI_COMM_WORLD size)`. Is this behavior expected from BLACS? Many thanks again for your support!

Comment: I don't have a good answer for you, but if you don't get something here, I'd suggest reposting this question on http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/. This question is probably on topic on both sites, but you're more likely to find the right experts (BLACS/ScaLAPACK) over there. You can also try the mailing lists.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, I am going to repost my question on  scicomp.stackexchange.com. I have also a small update for my problem which maybe can be useful to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A few interesting links about this matter:

- [A post from J. Langou](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/archives/scalapack/msg00065.html)
- [Article about MPI/ScaLAPACK relations](http://www.netlib.org/blacs/mpiblacs_issues.ps) (pdf)

In case it helps anyone, for me the problem was that I used `Csys2blacs_handle()` (the C wrapper) and then `blacs_gridinit_()` (the Fortran interface). It seems silly but you should check twice that you did not mix them.

A remark for debugging purpose: with the Fortran interface the context integer is similar to a MPI communicator (very large integer), but with the C wrapper it is a small integer (0,1..).

The solution was to replace `blacs_gridinit_()` with `Cblacs_gridinit()`.